# Best practice - converting an internal value to one that is suitable for display / print purposes and vice versa

Tags: php, database

I'm dealing with a fairly simple project management system that runs on PHP and MySQL. There's a lot of cases where I have an ID for a property stored in the database, but obviously the ID is not what I want to display to the user.

I'm in the middle of a major refactor and this is something I'd like to rework. Up until now, I've been manually looking up (that is, querying for it whenever I need to print it) the proper value for the 'name' of a property that corresponds to its ID.

Now, I've changed some aspects of the system to be neater and converted some procedural things to Objects. What I've come up with so far are functions like prep_db() and prep_display() that prepare the attributes of the object to be suitable for either entering into the database, or printing out and displaying. But this isn't very neat.

The other idea I've had is to have two properties for these parts of the object which are both filled out upon construction, say project_type_disp (for displaying) and project_type_id (for database purposes), and using the right one for the right occasion, but that also doesn't seem very neat.

Is there a best practice for this sort of thing?

Comment: I didn't quite get your question. You have some IDs and that are mapped to some strings that you want to display instead of the IDs? Just add some sort of adapter to your code flow that uses the given mapping.

Comment: Right. The functions I was talking about are basically one-way adapters. For some reason this solution doesn't sit perfectly well with me, but I guess it's the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend simply adding a getDisplayName() method  (or similar) to your object(s). Everywhere you want to display the identifier, just output the return value of that method:

```
echo $obj->getDisplayName();
```

If you later decide you want to change what gets displayed, it's a one-line change that affects every display location. For example, it could be as simple as:

```
public function getDisplayName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

Or perhaps you want to embed the ID as well:

```
public function getDisplayName()
{
    return '[' . $this->id . '] ' . $this->name;
}
```

You might also make a magic wrapper for casting to string:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getDisplayName();
}
```

Then you can just refer to the object as a string:

```
echo $obj;
```

Comment: Ugh. Of course! Not sure why I didn't think of this solution. Also, thanks for the __toString() tip, that should be really useful!